# Openshift pods are stuck in Error syncing pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Im running:

- **OpenShift Master:** v3.6.0+c4dd4cf
- **Kubernetes Master:** v1.6.1+5115d708d7

I had to restart the master node, and some pods are failing to start.

When I `describe` the problematic pods I see:

```
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                SubObjectPath   Type        Reason      Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----                -------------   --------    ------      -------
  3m        3m      1   default-scheduler               Normal      Scheduled   Successfully assigned mds-3-build to apps.teammachine.us
  3m        8s      15  kubelet, my.domain.com          Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod
```

No where does it provide any useful information in the `describe` output besides the `Error Syncing Pod` message.

What can I do to fix, and troubleshoot, this issue?

Comment: Try to check your pod's log:  `kubectl logs mds-3-build -n <namespace>`

Comment: might be worth checking the events also

Answer (score 2):

run this command:

`oc get events`

That should give you more useful information.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't give more info 